# Getting and error like on SPFX webpart "Deploying a domain isolated package on a site collection app catalog is not supported."

Tags: sharepoint, office365, spfx

I created "hello-world.sppkg" with a command "gulp package-solution" and uploaded to App catalog "Apps for SharePoint" of SharePoint Online site collection.
But it is showing an error "Deploying a domain isolated package on a site collection app catalog is not supported. Correlation ID: 8c21019f-4030-1000-7ae4-685b56b9ac00"

And i am not able to add this web part to page as it is not shown.
see below picture 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be honest and say I'm not sure what the cause is but if I were to make a guess, you probably enabled something that shouldn't be enabled for what you're trying to do. I notice the name of your webpart is hello-world so I recommend you just re-create the web-part if that's an option as you might not get an answer.

If you really want to resolve this issue, I recommend you compare your json files in your web-part with a freshly created web-part, see if any settings don't match and figure out why.

Comment: Yes zain your guess was right, it was some configuration which was creating that issue created new webpart with default configuration and move my code to that  and it works fine.